# Play Video Url in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4, xcode4.2

How To play *Server URL Video* in Iphone ?
how to play video from url using `MPMoviePlayer` ?

```
 (void)loadVideo {

     videoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://movies.apple.com/media/us/mac/getamac/2009/apple-mvp-biohazard_suit-us-20090419_480x272.mov"]];
       if(videoUrl) {

        if([videoUrl scheme]) {

            [self playVideoStream:videoUrl];
        }
    }
}

-(void)playVideoStream:(NSURL *)movieFileURL {

MPMovieSourceType movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
/* If we have a streaming url then specify the movie source type. */
if ([[movieFileURL pathExtension] compare:@"mov" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) 
{
    movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
}
[self createAndPlayMovieForURL:movieFileURL sourceType:movieSourceType]; 
}

-(void)createAndPlayMovieForURL:(NSURL *)movieURL sourceType:(MPMovieSourceType)sourceType {

/* Play the video! */    
[moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:sourceType];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];;
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 280, 210);  
[customVideoView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Good , But where is the question

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `contentURL` property at fisrt

```
moviePlayer.contentURL = urlVideo;

[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  {

      NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"//name of your video here" ofType:@"//format e.g. mp4, m4v"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];

playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[playerController.moviePlayer play];


// When movie finished loading you can have a notification and do extra code
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MovieDidLoad:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];



[playerController release];

playerController = nil;
  }


  -(void)MovieDidLoad:(NSNotification *)notification {

  NSLog(@"logged and notification is %@", notification);

 // extra code if needed


   }
```

Comment: [playerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy way is to load that video url into a `UIWebview`.